# Complex functions. Find the region of the plane

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the region of the plane onto which the function $e^z$ maps $\{z\in\mathbb{C}|\operatorname{Re}(z)\operatorname{Im}(z)=0\}$

I was told $e^z $ is periodic with period $2\pi i$ but I'm not sure if its relevant to the question or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, what does the condition mean? $\mathrm{Im}(z)=0$ or $\mathrm{Re}(z)=0$, that it, the given set is the union of the real axis and the imaginary axis.

Now, the imaginary axis is mapped onto the curve $z=e^{it}$ with $t \in \mathbb{R}$, which is the [unit circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle).
And the real axis is mapped onto the half-line (or *[ray](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_%28geometry%29#Ray)*) $z=t$, for $t>0$.

Thus the image by $\exp$ is the union of the unit circle and this half-line.